# Add update or delete database records using custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, database

I need my client to be able to go in his wordpress backend, select "markers" and I want to present him a screen which shows all the data fetched from just 1 database table.

In here he can then choose to delete, update or insert a new record in that table.

How do I go about this? I have no idea where to even start looking.

I realize an option is to just do this in a (secured) webpage, which would make it easier, but I want it to be available in the wordpress backend.